# Mutual independece problem with two dices X Y and their sum mod 6 Z

Tags: probability

I got a problem from my probability class, we just learned what is mutual independence

[image: mutually independence definition]

Then I faced this problem,

[image: question]

It seems not so difficult but when do it in practice I got confused,

Though X and Y are obviously independent, I don't now how to prove Y and Z are also independent because I have no idea how to transform P(Y,Z) <--> P(Y)P(Z),

I have tried to list all the probabilities, not useful, I also write something like 
$P(Y,Z) = P(Z,Y) = P(Z)P(Z\mid Y) = P(Z\mid (X+Y)\bmod6)$, then no next, and the more I try, the more I even feel Y and Z are not independent...

So could you give me some hints on why Y and Z are independent? Please feel free to share your opinion, thank you!

Comment: Listing all the probabilities is useful, IMO, to see the pattern. For  6-sided dice that's 36 values (for how X and Y can turn out, which determie the value of Z). If that's to much work for starters, consider "half dies" that only create uniformly random number $1,2$ or $3$. Then you need to take $Z=X+Y \mod 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key observation is that both dice are fair, and hence $Z$ has the same distribution as both $X$ and $Y$. This can be verified by writing out the possibilities for the event $Z=i$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$ for every $i\in \{1,\ldots,6\}$.

You can then proceed as follows. Let $i,j \in \{1,\ldots,6\}$. Then
$\mathbb{P}(Z=i, Y=j) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y = i, Y=j) = \mathbb{P}(X=i-j (\operatorname{mod} 6), Y=j)$

Since $X,Y$ are independent and the dice are fair, you can then write
$\mathbb{P}(X=i-j (\operatorname{mod} 6), Y=j) = \mathbb{P}(X=i-j (\operatorname{mod} 6)) \mathbb{P}(Y=j) = \mathbb{P}(Z=i) \mathbb{P}(Y=j)$
The last equality follows from the above stated fact that both $Z$ and $X$ are uniformly distributed on $\{1,\ldots,6\}$.